# Why will it only open if opened in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried adding the link but it can only be opened in new tab. Not when you click it.

```html
<a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>                        
<a href="#playtoearn" class="nav-link">Play to Earn</a>
<a href="#tokenomics" class="nav-link">Tokenomics</a>
<a href="#whitepaper" class="nav-link">White Paper</a>
<a href="#support" class="nav-link" style="display: inline;"><span class="support">Support</span></a>
```

So where it says tokenomics it scrolls down to where you want it. As far as White Paper and Play to Earn it was supposed to bring to another page. Which doesn't do that. The man I paid is very slow with communication and I did try changing the # to the link, but you must open in a new tab.

EDIT: This is the app.js

```
  const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },

  // autoplay: {
  //   delay: 5000,
  // },

  speed: 800,
  loop: true,

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
  
  // Smooth scrolling
  $("nav a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = $(this).attr("href");
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top  -100 }, 500);
  });


  const header = document.querySelector('.header')
  let toggler = document.querySelector('.toggler');
  
  toggler.onclick = ()=> {
    header.classList.add('navbar-bg')
    toggler.firstChild.classList.toggle("fa-times")
    toggler.firstChild.classList.toggle("fa-bars")
  }
  

  document.body.onscroll = () => {
  
    if (document.body.scrollTop == 0  && !toggler.firstChild.classList.contains('fa-times')) {
      header.classList.remove('navbar-bg')
    } else {
      header.classList.add('navbar-bg')
    }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

See how there is

```
$("nav a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = $(this).attr("href");
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top  -100 }, 500);

});
```

The JavaScript is saying that all the anchor should prevent its default function and run following code after that.

Basically if you want code to just scroll in between the page you use that.
My solution would be tojust target the elemt that you want to scroll in page and let other do its default action.

Edit you code as below where

```
<a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>                        
<a href="#playtoearn" class="nav-link">Play to Earn</a>
<a href="#tokenomics" class="nav-link scrollWithinPage">Tokenomics</a>
<a href="#whitepaper" class="nav-link">White Paper</a>
<a href="#support" class="nav-link" style="display: inline;"><span class="support">Support</span></a>
```

And JavaScript as

```
  $("a.scrollWithinPage").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = $(this).attr("href");
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top  -100 }, 500);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you I added to the post. Hopefully that helps.